# how to find "bottleneck"?

Tags: wpf, profiling

I have an WPF application, which do very slow an operation. The same operation does quickly second time. This operation uses third-party components. Seems, it's loading some libraries or something else. How can I found, what happens to fix it?

Comment: Get a profiling tool on it. Can't say from here what's going on. Could be a huge JIT, to load your assemblies, a setup / initialisation task to make it quick the second time, or just poor design somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible thing you can do is watch the output window while it is running in the Debugger. This will write a line for each assembly that is loaded so if your theory is correct then you will see lots of lines added while the slowness occurs.

In my experience this isn't the usual cause of delays such as this.

A far better solution is to get hold of a profiler, there are quite a few out there with trial periods so you can evaluate which most meets your needs, see Ants from redgate or DotTrace by Jetbrains. These will let you find out exactly where the delays are occuring.